# Get the next event using date_query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, date

I created a CPT called event and want to make a query to show the next future event, based on it's publish date.

Here is the `WP_Query` args:

```
$today = getdate();
$args = array(
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'future'),
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'date_query' =>
        array(
            array(
                'year'  => $today['year'],
                'compare'   => '>=',
            ),
            array(
                'month' => $today['mon'],
                'compare' => '>=',
            ),
            array(
                'day' => $today['mday'],
                'compare' => '>=',
            )
        )
);
```

It's work fine when there is event in the current month. But now, the next event is on april, and the script don't show anything.

**SOLUTION**

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'future'),
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'date_query' =>
        array(
            'after' => 'today'
        )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure without running which query precisely this results in, but I don't think it is intended format for such query.

If you take a look at [Date Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) documentation, there is a special case of `after` and `before` when you want to find posts in some direction from specific point.